# Errors in SharePoint 2016 Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2016, error

A strange thing is noticed in the worker workflow list. There are three workflows in the list and one day workflows started to fail, producing an error: "The item could not be updated in the workflow, possibly because one or more columns for this item should contain data of another type." The most interesting error can be transmitted through workflows. For example: if you re-publish through SharePoint Designer everything is perfectly published normally, and an error of this format may be displayed on another workflow, and the one that generated the error to make money. If you try to create a workflow for the list, it gives an error: (121, 15) The field cannot have the type void).

This error was noticed when creating a workflow for the site and managed to solve it by installing updates for SharePoint.

What to do with the list?

Comment: Interesting case, can you share what error you are getting in the ULS Logs. Could it be the case that someone has deleted an column (by mistake) and try to recreate it (and used wrong type of column) ie lookup change for choice or something similar.

Comment: There is nothing sensible in the ULS magazine. The last actions were performed as in this article    https://7392219446306130432_1a3fe57f8fd3ee96e1a8224565f469f4a4d48ada.blogspot.com/2012/12/sharepoint-2010.html, but I did not have a "Name" column I had to create

Comment: Maybe someone changed one of the columns to required. It doesn't have to be exact same column.